# windows service msi installer created in vs2003 hangs in win7 while installing

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, windows-installer

We have few windows services developed using .Net framework 1.1(VS2003).For each windows service an msi installer(set up project) is created to make installation easier.These installers are able to install windows services successfully in windows XP.But these installers unable to install windows service in WIN7 though I have admin privileges on the machine in which I am trying install them.While I am trying  to install the windows service in win7, Through msi installer,installation is progressing till 90%.After that it is neither completing nor throwing an error.I am unable to understand what the problem is.

I tried following ways.

1.Opened cmd window in admin mode and tried to execute the msi with the command msiexec -i  --Din't work

2.Right clicked on the actual exe(windows service exe) file and tried to run it in admin mode.--Din't work

3.Changed the UAC to never notify, restarted the machine and then tried to install--Din't work

4.Right clicked on both exe and msi and open their properties and changed the compatibility to lower version of windows and tried to install--Din't work

One thing I have noticed is that for all the custom actions of our windows service installer, primary output of our main project(exe) was given as input.I build the msi installer by removing all the custom actions.Then i tried to install it in win7.Then it was installed.But during the installation system not prompted for account details  (which is the actual case while installing windows service) and also the service was not appeared in services manager window.

I spent somuch time to identify the cause and resolution.But I dint find any posts on this issue.I suspect that the problem is with custom actions.But not sure.If the problem is with custom actions please let me know how to overcome it.

Please provide a resolution for this issue or share me if there are any links which talks about this.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, .NET 1.1 isn't supported on Win7.  Also I'm guessing you are using InstallUtil custom actions to drive the setup of your .NET Windows Service.  These are very fragile and you can eliminate all those brittle points by refactoring and using the ServiceInstall ServiceControl tables in MSI.